# Perl Make GLOB ignore case

Tags: perl

How can i make the following line ignore case

```
perl -MFile::Glob=:bsd_glob -lne 'unlink glob' -- /volume1/<file.list
```

I tried experimenting with `GLOB_NOCASE` but i might be placing it wrong or it will never work.

Who can please help me make the lookup and delete ignore case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not at all clear IMHO from [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html) however it appears that when using `:bsd_glob`, the behavior is determined by explicitly importing `:nocase`

Ex.

```
$ perl -MFile::Glob=:bsd_glob,:nocase -le 'BEGIN{print for glob("*.bar")}'
baz.BAR
foo.bar
```

Comment: going to try that in my script, look promising

Comment: The command works well when i tested it